# how to publish kinect laser scan 2d image in a browser

Tags: rviz, turtlebot, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.. I am interested in publishing a kinect laser scan in a  browser to be broadcast over the internet. Something that is close to a player laser scan image or a rviz 2dnav image would be perfect. I am currently using WebUi to control my turtlebot with button control for cmd_vel and a video cam feed to view the environment. But I would like to transmit the kinect 2dnav scan like in rviz to get a idea of where I might be in a saved map with a view of the current laser scan in the browser. I was thinking about a screen image broadcast of the rviz window in place of a webcam image but I hope that someone on here might be able to point me to better solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41223/how-to-publish-kinect-laser-scan-2d-image-in-a-browser/) by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 458 on 2012-08-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosjs / rosbridge are probably your best bet. This uses javascript to talk to a ROS master over the internet. There's a barebones tutorial on how to use the rosbridge visualization stuff here that can probably get you started: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjs_tutorials/Tutorials/Visualization

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2012-08-15**:
Thanks Jonathan for the reply... I have known about rosjs and all the cool features coming out of the stack. But was intimidated on approaching it on my own but now seems like a better time than ever. Your link is definitely the place to start, do you know of any good examples that might be useful?

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-08-15**:
You can probably look at wviz: http://www.ros.org/wiki/wviz Unfortunately, their tutorials appear to be hollow.